# How many times you can play Google drive video?

Tags: google-drive-api

How many times you can play Google drive video without getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar if there are any limits regarding video streaming but as it is also discussed in this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleDrive/comments/3579zx/google_drive_video_length_limit/), "Google Drive was 'not designed' to stream video of any length." I would suggest to use [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) for uploading, searching deleting videos or [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for streaming videos for web, [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) for android and [Embed YouTube Videos in iOS Applications with the YouTube Helper Library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) for iOS.